# Cloudflare - CPanel - Parallelize downloads across hostnames

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, cloudflare, cname

I have a wordpress website which is using Cloudflare. So basically, I created a Cloudflare account and setup everything including changing the nameservers so that the domain goes through Cloudflare first.

Let's say my domain is **domain.com**.

Now I have a sub-domain called **temp.domain.com** in which I need to parallelize downloads across hostnames.

All the necessary wordpress code (shown below) is already in place in **functions.php**.

```
function parallelize_hostnames($url, $id) {
     $hostname = par_get_hostname($url);
     $url =  str_replace(parse_url(get_bloginfo('url'), PHP_URL_HOST), $hostname, $url);
     return $url;
}

function par_get_hostname($name) {
    $subdomains = array('temp1.domain.com','temp2.domain.com', 'temp3.domain.com);
    $host = abs(crc32(basename($name)) % count($subdomains));
    $hostname = $subdomains[$host];
    return $hostname;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'parallelize_hostnames', 10, 2);
```

So after following a tutorial, I set 3 **A** records in Cloudflare called **temp1.domain.com**, **temp2.domain.com** and **temp3.domain.com** to point to my server's IP address.

Then in my CPanel I set 3 CNAME records **with the same 3 names** all pointing to **temp.domain.com**

Waited more than a day and now when I visit temp1.domain.com, temp2.domain.com or temp3.domain.com, I always get a hostgator 404 page.

What am I doing wrong please? Does this setup make sense?

The wordpress code is working since I could verify this in the browser console. However, all media requests via **temp1**, **temp2** and **temp3** are giving a NOT FOUND error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

1. Removing all A records from Cloudflare and cname records from CPanel
2. Creating 3 sub domains (temp1, temp2, temp3) in cpanel pointing to the same directory (temp.domain.com)
3. Recreated the relevant A records in Cloudflare

Everything worked like a charm then! I was also told that CPanel is not fully compatible with Cloudflare in certain areas.